# Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given on line no 22

Tags: php, mysqli

I cannot find out what's wrong in this code. Since the query executes and insert also works but the error msg shows:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given on line no 22. I cannot solve this.

```
<?php

require_once('db_config.php');
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
{
    $name = $_POST['Name'];
    $mob = $_POST['Mob'];
    $username = $_POST['Username'];
    $password = $_POST['Password'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO user (name,phone,username,password) VALUES ('$name','$mob','$username','$password')";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));

    $check = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if(isset($check)){
        echo "sucess";
    }else{
        echo "error";
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
}

?>
```

Comment: `name` is a reserved keyword in mysql so if you use it as a field name you need to use backticks https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html. You're also vulnerable to injection attack

Comment: Does this answer your question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole

Comment: also read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection

Comment: @Tristan `name` is not a reserved word, it is a keyword (2 different animals). As per the manual, there is no `(R)` next to it.

Comment: put this after mysqli_query() to see whats going on. if (!$result) { printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con)); exit(); }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your SQL is an `INSERT` query, there will be no result set. The result will be the boolean `TRUE` if the insert was successful, or `FALSE` if not. So instead of `$check = mysqli_fetch_array($result);` you can simply say;

```
if ($result === TRUE) {
    echo "success";
}
else {
    echo "error";
}
```

Comment: If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

[mysqli_query manual page](http://docs.php.net/mysqli_query):

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

Therefore $result is already what you want to check for TRUE/FALSE; and not something you want to pass to mysqli_fetch_*.

Please have read of [PHP: SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and also consider using [prepared statements+parameters](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

```
<?php
require_once('db_config.php');
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
    if (!isset($_POST['Name'], $_POST['Mob'], $_POST['Username'], $_POST['Password']) ) {
        die('missing POST parameter');
    }

    $name = $con->escape_string($_POST['Name']);
    $mob = $con->escape_string($_POST['Mob']);
    $username = $con->escape_string($_POST['Username']);
    $password = $con->escape_string($_POST['Password']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO user (name,phone,username,password) VALUES ('$name','$mob','$username','$password')";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if( $result ) {
        echo "sucess";
    }
    else {
        echo "error";
    }
}
else {
    // you should do something/print here....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take 
 MySQL® Databases from Cpanel then click on the privilaged users. After that, ensure 'allow all privileges is checked'. Then execute your php.